Using custom Bootstrap Angular
I have a problem I was not able to solve concerning Angular. I created a Spring web using Moustache and Bootstrap. Now I want to do the front using Angular, but I am not able to implement it.
This is what I have done:

ppm install bootstrap

Adding styles in angular.json as shown:


npm start

I get these errors:



My folder is at: Tatademy/src/main/resources/static/assets
And Angular json is At: Tatademy/TatademySPA/angular.json
Can anyone help me?

Do you have an /src/main/resources/static/assets/fonts/Feather.svg?

Maybe it's the way you are using the import. Try it this way.
"styles": [
   "src/main/resources/static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",  
],

If you have any further questions, you can consult this content.
